# Various types of queries not working in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

Just upgraded to MAMP4 from MAMP3, which meant going from mySQL 5.5 to 5.6.  Everything works fine except PHPMyAdmin version 4.6.5.2.  This purports to be compatible with mySQL 5.6, but it doesn't seem to work.  Browsing a table works, but when I do a SQL query inside of phpMyAdmin, it always fails and just returns the entire table.  Similarly, changing the sort by key just fails silently and returns the table sorted in the default way.

Here's another example of something that doesn't work: I can browse a table's rows, it works fine.
[image: browse all rows in phpymadmin]

But when I click edit on one of the rows, it shows blank entries: 
[image: edit of a row in phpymadmin]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up changing the PHP version from 5.6.30 to 5.6.29 (on the advice of the MAMP Support people), and it worked.